# PHP Blacklist checker script

Tags: php, mysql, blacklist

I want to create an system to check some emails from a list, if there are blacklisted or not. More example, I want to create a MySQL table where is put some emails like @gmail.com or @yahoo.com

Now, I want to create a PHP function that check if email is on blacklist, for example on a registration form, user try to join with an email like somebody@yahoo.com, I want to return error, because @yahoo.com is on blacklist. I don't know to explain better, but I think you understand what I want.

Comment: What problem(s) are you running into?

Comment: I don't know how can to create a function to check in array with preg_match (or something) to see if email is on blacklist or not. I need some help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//array of blacklisted domains
$domains = //sql call here

foreach($domains as $domain){    
    if(strpos($email, $domain) !== 0)
    {
        //this email is in blacklist
    }
}
```